# Does scheduling a java.util.timer exit that timer's timerTask method?

Tags: java, timer

Suppose I have a class that looks something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass extends JFrame
{
private java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
...
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        doStuff();

        if (conditionIsMet())
        {
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 500);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now I have always thought of the run method of a `TimerTask` somewhat like a loop. It runs once, then, if you want to run it again you can do so by calling `schedule`. So my question is: When I call `timer.schedule()` does it execute any other code in the `TimerTask` or does it act as if I used `break` in a loop? If I wrote the method like this instead:

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        doStuff();

        if (conditionIsMet())
        {
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 1000); // method wouldn't end after this call
        }

        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 500);
    }
```

Would it function the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduling a timer task is just a method call; it does not cause the current execution of the timer task's run() method to end, so no, the two code examples do not function the same.  It's better practice to use the first of your two code examples, scheduling the task only once in the run method.

Comment: and so the answer is no